# How can I solve 404 error while executing docker ps command

Tags: docker

I'm setting a docker to run a application on my custom board,i have made a custom build environment to run docker on my board,and it was successfull.But when i execute `docker ps` command it shows error

```
ERROR:Error response from daemon: 404 page not found.
```

ERROR Message

```
docker ps
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
root@salvator-x:~# [  143.758164] audit_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed
[  143.763172] audit: type=1325 audit(1553864701.319:13): table=nat family=2 entries=8
[  143.770891] audit: type=1300 audit(1553864701.319:13): arch=c00000b7 syscall=208 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=0 a2=40 a3=3d8e0a90 items=0 ppid=3345 pid=3374 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/usr/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
[  143.798210] audit: type=1327 audit(1553864701.319:13): proctitle=2F7573722F7362696E2F69707461626C6573002D2D77616974002D74006E6174002D4600444F434B4552
[  143.815500] audit: type=1325 audit(1553864701.375:14): table=nat family=2 entries=8
```

Comment: Could you add more details about the environment (OS, docker version, how did you installed)?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $DOCKER_HOST`

Answer (score 0):

at first, check if you have any proxy in your envirement with this command:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

now remove content of this below path:

```
/var/lib/docker/network/
```

if it's still not working, reinstall docker.

Comment: env | grep -i proxy

Command is not working on my board.So in order to avoid those proxy i have made custom IP for the board and Network coonection is established.But still i have the same ERROR.

I've done some research and seen that others are reporting this problem does not occur with Docker 1.8.3.I am cuurently have the version 1.9.0,So i decided to tryout by downgrading the version.How can i downgrade the current docker version.